# XSLT - How to get the xml element text along with the child element attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a below XML. I want to get the text value of Title element. I have used <xsl:value-of select="../title/text()"/>,But it does not fetch the output.

XML

```
 <data>
    <title><artist all="type" artistid="Many"/> 1999 Grammy Nominees </title>
 </data>
 <data>
    <title>Not Many Nominees <artist all="type" artistid="Only Few"/> </title>
 </data>
```

I used title/artist template then getting the attribute value @artistid `'Many'`. Also I want the Text  `'1999 Grammy Nominees'`

Output I want is,

```
<fo:block>Many 1999 Grammy Nominees</fo:block>

<fo:block>Not Many Nominees Only Few</fo:block>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match=" title/artist">   
  <fo:block>      
    <xsl:value-of select="@artistid"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="../title/text()" //not sure
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't how to get the text(1999 Grammy Nominees).How to get the xml element `<title>` text along with the child element attribute value by giving XPATH as title/artist using XSLT-1.0. Also, how exactly we get the order of the text as First fo:block as attribute value followed by text. Second fo:block should need to have text then attribute value

Please Help!!!

Comment: Your input snippet is not even well-formed XML but in general, if you want all text from e.g. the title element use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="../title"/>`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen, tried that too still not getting the value '1999 Grammy Nominees'

Comment: Please edit your question to show a well-formed XML sample so that we can see the real XML structure.

Comment: closing artist tag is still missing

Comment: And so is a root element.

Comment: <title> is my root element <artist> is child of <title>

Comment: `title` is NOT the root element.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

With a **well-formed(!!!)** XML input such as:

```
<catalog>
    <data>
        <title><artist all="type" artistid="Many"/> 1999 Grammy Nominees </title>
    </data>
    <data>
        <title>Not Many Nominees <artist all="type" artistid="Only Few"/> </title>
    </data>
</catalog>
```

you can use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">  
    <result>      
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </result>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">   
    <block>      
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">   
    <xsl:value-of select="@artistid"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <block>Many 1999 Grammy Nominees </block>
  <block>Not Many Nominees Only Few</block>
</result>
```

Make the necessary adjustments for your situation.